# What is causing the letter to the right of my point to flicker?

Tags: point

I occasionally have the problem that the character to the right of my point starts blinking. Can anyone think of anything that could be causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: The best way to debug this would be to start up emacs -Q and enable your customizations one by one until you see which one causes the problem. Also it would be helpful to know all the minor modes you have active. Use `describe-mode` to get a list.

Comment: That's a very good point. I'll post with an EDIT once I've debugged more of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is a known phenomenon caused when Emacs has too many timers active with small intervals.  A known package exhibiting this problem would be popwin.  If you have helm installed, you can view these with M-x helm-timers.

Comment: @wasamasa is that phenomenon a bug or a feature?

Comment: Looks like a font-lock bug to me, but still, this timer situation shouldn't happen in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs comes with a timer feature that allows you to run a function in periodical intervals.  Some packages abuse this feature by setting their timer intervals very low (around 0.01s) and use it for polling, if they don't manage cleaning up the timers after themselves and leave spurious ones in the `timer-list`, one after-effect is flickering of letters after point in syntax-highlighted buffers (the other one is more wakeups/CPU usage than necessary).

To check up whether that's the cause of your problem, inspect this timer list with `F1 v timer-list` (or with `M-x helm-timers` if you've got [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) installed) and see whether it contains repeated entries that can be traced back to a specific package.  I used to have such problems with the [Auto-Complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete), popwin and helm packages (though, helm seems to have finally fixed it, I've migrated from Auto-Complete to [company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode)).  Either get the packages themselves fixed (be it by handing in a pull request or submitting a ticket on their issue tracker), write better ones (what I did with popwin in favour of [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle)) or just abstain from them completely.

Comment: I found removing the flymake configuration from my .emacs and using flycheck instead removed the cause of this problem for me.